# Use jquery to detect which element is clicked and place it in a seperate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

I have several images, which I would want to be shown in a seperate bigger div when clicked. However, I can't seem to find a way to detect which image has been clicked and then to be placed in the div. If there is a way, please someone help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign classes to the images and then, after the click event is fired, use the $(this) element inside it. Assigning the same class to each image will make the event "click" bind every image with your class, then $(this) will refer only to the clicked image.

Example (that does exactly what you want):

```
$(".myImages").click(function() {
  $(this).detach().appendTo('#finalContainer');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery click function and bind it to you images and do what you describe in the on click function.
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

You can structure html like:

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="thumbnails" alt="1">
<img src="2.jpg" class="thumbnails" alt="2">
<img src="3.jpg" class="thumbnails" alt="3">
<img src="4.jpg" class="thumbnails" alt="4">
<img src="5.jpg" class="thumbnails" alt="5">
<div class="largeImage"></div>
```

Then this script will do your task:

```
    $(".thumbnails").on("click",function(){
        $(".largeImage").css('background-image','url('+$(this).attr("src")+')')
    })
```